# Wix bootstrapper having trouble with an MSI requiring SelfReg with VC++ 2005

Tags: wix

So I have a Wix bootstrapper that installs VC++ 2005 (x86) Redistributable among other things and also installs a 3rd party MSI that keeps failing on a failed SelfReg of one of its dlls.  When I install VC++ 2005 (x86) outside of the bootstrapper everything works fine and the bootstrapper chain skips the VC++ install and the installs the MSI requiring the SelfRegs without issue.  However, when I have my bootstrapper install the VC++ Redistributable before the MSI it depends on it fails because the SelfRegs fail.

Now if I were to guess the issue may have something to do with environment variables not getting refreshed during the bootstrapper chain and thus a reboot could fix it.  I would prefer an alternative solution and was wondering if someone else may have an idea of what's happening and give me an alternative.

Update:
So when I hit the point of failure, I can confirm that VC++ 2005 (x86) is installed in both the log files, the registry key at HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/DevDiv/VC/8.0/RED/1033/Install, and manifest files in C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests.  When I run sxstrace while trying to self-register the DLLs manually with Regsvr32.exe I get this log.

```
 =================
 Begin Activation Context Generation.
 Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\PersonalCategory.dll
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\
    Application Config File = 
 -----------------
 INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\PersonalCategory.dll.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.ATL,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053"
 INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.4053__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.8428_none_516ac2a30f4be7a6.manifest
                INFO: Publisher Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.8428".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.8428_none_d08a11e2442dc25d.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.8428_none_d08a11e2442dc25d.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
 INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.8428".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.8428_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.8428_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.8428_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.8428_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
 INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.ATL,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.ATL\8.0.50727.4053__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.ATL\8.0.50727.4053__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\Microsoft.VC80.ATL\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\Microsoft.VC80.ATL\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.ATL,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053".
 ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
 End Activation Context Generation.
```

Also snapped this pick on doing a Dependency Walker on the dll.
[image]

Comment: Assuming your guess or something similar is right, it proves the point of avoiding self-registration and custom actions in general. Too bad the problem is in a 3rd-party installer.

Answer (score 0):

There could be few other reasons such as some dependency missing or  the user context under which the bootstrapper executes is different from the working scenario.

The first thing i would do here is to inspect the windows installer logs.
To generate , windows installer logs, you can follow the following link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/03/29/help-me-help-you-if-you-have-setup-bugs.aspx

-How are you executing your installer outside of the bootstrapper?
Are you installing them in silent mode? Its important to do this as the bootstrapper installs the msi's in silent mode. 
Are you installing them over an elevated command prompt?

I am asking the above questions as you state that the installation works outside of the bootstrapper.

-Once you hit the error with Self regs, do you get an error message?
If yes, instead of clicking on Ok and allowing the installation to roll back, can you go to the folder where the files are copied. Try to register the dll manually from the command prompt and see if you can register the dll.

if none of the above things work, please post a log file from the installation and then we can take it forward.

Comment: When I run the VC++ redistributable outside the installer I simply double click it and let it run there are no options in the MSI, it just runs with a progress bar.  When Wix installs the redistributable it passes it the extra arguments ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" which I doubt is causing the issue.

Comment: I've also paused the installer to try to do the registration myself but I'm not entirely sure what the SelfReg is doing.  I assume it's calling regsvr32.exe against the dll.  But when I have the installer pause and run a regsvr32 against it I get an incorrect side-by-side configuration is incorrect error.  Which seems consistent with the the VC++ issue.

Comment: Well, if you see a side by side error when you manually run regsvr32.exe, it means the dependencies are missing.  Have you confirmed **for sure** that the VC++ run time was installed?  ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" prevents the VC++ runtime from being displayed in the Add/Remove programs applet. MSIFASTINSTALL="7" makes the installation process faster. So theoretically, ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" should not be the cause of the issue. Couple of things to do here:  -Clear the event viewer before the installation. Inspect the event viewer after the installation.

Comment: Do you see any side by side errors?  -Make sure that the VC++ runtime is installed. Inspect the MSI logs from the VC++ installation to see if the installation was successful.   -Execute the VC++ and third party installers in the same sequence with the exact command line parameters and see the behavior.  -When you run the bootstrapper , does it prompt you for elevation? When you execute the VC++ installer directly, are you prompted for elevation?  -  There is a tool called sxstrace that you can make use of to diagnose side by side configuration errors.  When you stop the installer  to execute

Comment: regsvr32.exe manually, have sxstrace running and then execute regsvr32.exe. Inspect the output from sxstrace to see what is the side by side error. - The last thing i would do is to run procmon to see as to where the  files are being searched for. Its possible that the registration process is looking for the dependent files in another location . ProcMon is a tool from the sysinternals suite and can be downloaded for free.  Lastly, i think that this is just a case of missing dependencies

Comment: @Thermonuclear: Were you able to make any progress on this? Did the tool sxstrace hep? If so, do let us know as to what the issue was?

Comment: My apologies, no I haven't resolved the issue as other things came up.  However I should mention I made an interesting finding, the issue might only exist on Windows 8.1.  However to answer one of your questions, yes the MSI logs show a successful install of the VC++ dependencies.  I'll try to give the sxstrace a try tomorrow and let you know how that goes.

Comment: Update: I ran an install with debugging ready to test it with sxstrace but it actually installed fine.  I'm not convinced the issue has suddenly disappeared so I'll build a clean VM to do more testing hopefully tomorrow sometime.

Comment: Ok. The other thing i wanted to tell you is about another tool called Dependency walker. This tool will also tell you the dependencies required for a dll to load. Let us know the results of your tests and then we can take this forward

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I've added updated information to the original post if you're still around.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Its very clear that Microsoft.VC80.ATL,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053" is not being resolved. After you hit the error, what happens if you were to  run the VCredist msi package outside of the bootstrapper, using the same arguments as that used by the bootstrapper  and then try the registration? Also, in the directory where your file is present, are there also other runtime dll's copied locally? In the dependency walker , i see the following: Modules with different CPU types found.  Can you

Comment: confirm if the runtime dll's are not copied locally into your application directory?

Comment: If I try to rerun the VC++ installer after hitting the error I get an error: "Error 1316. The specified account already exists."  Unfortunately I cannot do this while it's paused trying to self-reg the dlls because I get the error that an installer is already running.  Trying to do it any other way is pointless as I've already established running the VC++ redistributable outside the the bootstrapper fixes it.

Comment: To answer your other question, the installer that fails due to self-reg problems installs all of its files locally to it's installation directory as I believe is standard before running registrations and yes there are other dlls which need similiar registrations in the same directory.  I also checked if the VC++ 2005 is installing any files and from the ones I checked it is installing all the files it should.

Comment: The next logical step is to make use of ProcessMonitor. In ProcessMonitor, set filters for  Microsoft.VC80.ATL and try the registration process. Look at the locations where the registration process attempts to load  Microsoft.VC80.ATL from. What do you see?  If ProcessMonitor reports it as found,  go to the location and inspect if the expected file is indeed found.

Comment: There is alot going on here especially in regards to manifests which I don't really understand however towards the end of the failed self-reg attempt I saw this.  csrss.exe 432 CreateFile C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32      \Microsoft.VC80.ATL\8.0.50727.4053__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.DLL PATH NOT FOUND Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, Impersonating: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Comment: Now upon investigation the folder C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32 \Microsoft.VC80.ATL\Microsoft.VC80.ATL doesn't exist but even more interesting is the fact that on one of my machines where I was able to successfully make the installation the folder doesn't exist either.

Comment: Well, the VC run times are located in C:\Windows\WinSxS. Its very clear that its a case of missing run times.  When your installation is running, can you locate  v 8.0.50727.4053 of  Microsoft.VC80.ATL under C:\Windows\WinSxS? Also, make sure that its the 32 bit version of  Microsoft.VC80.ATL. One other thing, if you were to copy the runtime dll's locally into the application folder, what do you observe?  There is something very simple here. I find it hard to believe that we have the runtimes installed but  running into issues.

Comment: Okay so when the registration breaks I was able to find a folder "x86_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_d1c738ec43578ea1" that contains a single file ATL80.dll which I assume is the dll you're asking about.  I dropped that into directory of the dll that fails and also included msvcp80.dll and msvcr80.dll located in a similiar directory name "x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_d08d7da0442a985d" under WinSxS.

Comment: Loading the file with DependencyWalker I now lists those dlls as found.  Attempting a registration while running sxstrace though I get the same log file posted above.  I'd like to mention that the other missing dependencies listed by DependencyWalker as missing such as API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL are still missing but they aren't mentioned in the sxstrace log so I assume they aren't part of the problem.

Comment: Copy all of  the dependent dll's locally and see if you can register. This having gone so far, do you think you can walk me through your problem? I am happy to help you. If you can think of a good screen sharing program, i am more than happy to sit with you over your issue and see what else i could do. I work in the Indian time zone(IST), so keep this in mind. Do send me a chat message as to how you would like to connect.